# Horizontal position of UISearchBar when using UISearchController and large titles

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller, preferslargetitles

UISearchController created and used like this in `viewDidLoad`

```
search = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
search.searchResultsUpdater = self
search.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
search.definesPresentationContext = true
search.searchBar.placeholder = "Search books"

navigationItem.searchController = search
```

**I need to change horizontal position** (offset, inset?) of the searchBar (search text field?) to align with title and content.

[image: issue]

I already tried to change the frame of searchBar in viewDidAppear (left pic below), but it goes back when text field becomes first responder (right pic).

[image: frame changed in viewDidLoad]
[image: frame is back when text field is first responder]

Is there any working solution?

Comment: If you use navigationItem.searchController you will get it at the default position. try navigationItem.titleView with custom view and add your search controller inside that custom view

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya, thanks for your comment!
It doesn't work when I try to do it though. Could you share an example, tip or an URL to a tutorial? 
Also I suppose this solution will remove default navigation look collapsing behaviour, which is unwanted.